# Fetching Recent mail by IMAP in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-4, gmail, imap

I am trying to fetch new incoming mail through IMAP protocol   ..my sample code is bellow--

```
task :receive_mail_new => :environment do 
#require 'rubygems'
require 'net/imap'
imap = Net::IMAP.new('imap.gmail.com', 993, true,nil, false)
#imap.authenticate('LOGIN','debasish.industrify2016@gmail.com','****')
imap.login('test@example.com', '********')
 imap.examine('INBOX')
imap.search(["RECENT"]).each do |id|
 envelope = imap.fetch(id, "ENVELOPE")[0].attr["ENVELOPE"]
 puts "#{envelope.from[0].name}: \t#{envelope.subject}"
end
imap.logout()
imap.disconnect()
end
```

when i run this code there is no response

when i add this line

```
imap = Net::IMAP.new('imap.gmail.com', 993, true,nil, false)
```

instate of

```
 imap.authenticate('LOGIN','test@example.com','****')
```

the error its shows

```
  Net::IMAP::NoResponseError: Unsupported AUTHENTICATE mechanism. 15mb877209661ieh
```

can any one help me?

Comment: Don't use your real email address unless you want your spam filter to work extra hard.

Comment: this line is not work imap.search(["RECENT"]).each do |id|  what can i do?